# Docker build halts for no reason at `gradle assemble` step when running on Google Cloud Build

Tags: docker, gradle, java-11, google-cloud-build

I deploy my current `couldbuild.yaml` configuration with `gcloud builds submit`. The first two steps for `gradle check` and `gradle test` work fine. When the final step for the `docker build` starts it only executes until

```
Step #2: Step 5/10 : RUN gradle assemble
Step #2:  ---> Running in 591d26cae427
```

And then exits with the following error message

```
Finished Step #2
ERROR
ERROR: build step 2 "gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker" failed: step exited with non-zero status: 2
```

Building an image out of the Dockerfile locally works fine. It takes a bit long on that problematic step so I wonder if there is a timeout/healthcheck coming in and interrupting the build process?

However here is my `cloudbuild.yaml` and Dockerfile.

```
FROM gradle:6.8.3-jdk11 as builder
USER root
WORKDIR /builder
ADD . /builder
RUN gradle assemble

FROM openjdk:11-slim
WORKDIR /app

EXPOSE 8080

COPY --from=builder /builder/build/libs/equipment-service.jar app.jar
CMD ["java", "-jar", "app.jar"]
```

```yaml
steps:
  - name: 'gradle:6.8.3-jdk11'
    entrypoint: 'gradle'
    args: [ 'test']
  - name: 'gradle:6.8.3-jdk11'
    entrypoint: 'gradle'
    args: [ 'check', '-x', 'test']
  - name: 'docker'
    args: [ 'build', '-t', 'eu.gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/equipment-service:$BUILD_ID', '.' ]
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
    args: [ 'push', 'eu.gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/equipment-service:$BUILD_ID']
```

And here is the detailed Cloud Build output: https://pastebin.com/Bd8BwcHE

Comment: It seemed a `timeout: '300s'` is missing in the `cloudbuild.yaml` it works now. However I see no reason why that `gradle clean assemble` takes so long